# Xpath unexpected output

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

```
<bib>
<book year="2015">
    <title>Xml Applications</title>
    <publisher>Wuhan University</publisher>
    <author>Zhang San</author>
    <author> Li Si </author>
</book>
<book year="2016">
    <title> Xml Applications </title>
    <publisher>Qinghua University</publisher>
    <author>Zhang San </author>
    <author>Wang Wu</author>
</book>
<book year="2017">
    <title>XML Development Techniques</title>
    <publisher>Wuhan University</publisher>
    <author>Li Si</author>
    <author> Wang Wu </author>
</book>
<book year="2018">
    <title> XML Development Techniques </title>
    <publisher>Qinghua University</publisher>
    <author>Wang Wu </author>
    <author>Ma Liu</author>
</book>
</bib>
```

I am trying to get books written by `Zhang San`. The XPath expression i wrote is `//book[author = "Zhang San"]`. Problem is I only get one result `<book year=2015/>`. I am not getting the other result `<book year=2016/>`. When I try to get books published by **Wuhan University** `//book[publisher = "Wuhan University"]` I get the books published `<book year=2015/>` and `<book year=2017/>` which is right. Is there a reason the XPath expression I wrote for the author doesn't give the expected result? How can i write it to get both results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Zhang San " < author >

There is a space here after "San" in 2016.

Comment: Oh man, really. I didn't know such spaces affected results. Thank you for the help.